# How to best store an internal HDD for long-term backup

Tags: hard-drive, backup, storage

I have an HDD which I plan to use as backup media for some of my files; that is, I intend to *not* use it regularly. It's an internal 3.5" drive.

My question is: How should I best store it? That is, in what environment, and what should I put it in (get some specialty enclosure, bubble wrap, plastic box, etc.)

Note: I'm not asking about procedures for checking the data, or redundancy, or partitioning, or any of that stuff - just about how to physically store the drive.

Comment: Store it in a dry environment, without temperature extremes and far away from magnets. Definitely put it in a plastic container (like a tupperware). If there is possibility of dropping, perhaps put it in bubble wrap (or a bubble wrap envelope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality, you do not need anything special to store a hard drive. Despite what some people think, they are very robust pieces of hardware. Although not necessary, it wouldn't hurt to put it in an antistatic bag. Anything beyond that, like a padded box, is overkill.

Comment: @einpoklum Nope.  Hard drives can operate in every direction, even upside down. And do you really think hard drives sitting in a warehouse for months are carefully placed right side up?